# $version$ token in nuspec file not reading from AssemblyInfo.cs when nuget packaging an assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

When running "nuget pack" alone, it seems to read the csproj file and use
"Version" which I would like to auto increment the build version number.

When running "nuget pack nuspec.nuspec" it reads the nuspec file but produces this error:
"an error occurred while trying to parse the value '' of property 'version' in the manifest file"

Question: how do I auto increment the version value for the nuget package? I have managed to auto increment the assembly info version but I am unable to get nuget to read from the file. I just need a basic nuget package build version increment. And things like Major versions can be changed manually.

I am using .net framework and nuget.exe. version 5.8.1.7021

Comment: In you build, you can replace $version$ in the .nuspec file before pack command. Or you can use the argument `nuget pack -Version`.

Comment: Is $version$ meant to come from csproj or AssemblyInfo? "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#replacement-tokens" This seems to say it comes from AssemblyInfo but it comes from the csproj Version element for me

Comment: @JohnMcdowl, any update about this issue? If my answer helps you handle the issue, please do not forget to accept it. And if not, please feel free to let us know:)

Comment: @JohnMcdowl, does v5.6.0 solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

**Actually**, this is an issue on the latest recommended `nuget.exe v5.8.1`. I have tested it several times and all failed. Also, `nuget.exe v5.7.0` has the same issue.

**Solution**

**So** I suggest you could try to use [nuget.exe v5.6.0](https://www.nuget.org/downloads). It works well without any issues.

**Besides**, I have reported [the issue on our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1316506/nugetexe-v581-cannot-get-the-value-from-assemblyin.html). You can vote it and add any comments if I did not describe it in detail. Please track this ticket.

Comment: Thanks Mr Qian. This saves me a day! I'm pulling off my hair and could not find any clue what's the root cause.

Comment: Yes indeed - thanks a lot! BTW even 5.10 suffers from the same issue.